# What will happen if I activate my Windows XP VM?

Tags: windows, license, windows-activation

I made a Windows VM with Virtualbox in Ubuntu linux. I used the install disc that came with my laptop (I have a paid license for Windows XP). When I started my VM for the first time, it asked me to activate Windows, and said it will stop working in a month if I don't do this.

Is the a maximum number of times I can activate a VM?
Am I legally allowed to run Windows in a VM with my laptop's license?
I have a dual-boot set up--if I activate my VM, can I continue to use Windows natively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can activate Windows XP a handful (between 2-5, I have had different results) of times on different hardware or a generous amount if on the same hardware as the last activation (I did it at least 10 times without a problem.)

If you have a genuine reason for doing it and reach the limit, ring Microsoft on the free number and they are more than happy to allow you to continue / reset the counter. Activation is annoying and I am against it, but Microsoft have a better implementation than a few other companies and they will only block keys that are *massively* and obviously abused / overused.

That being said, if it was an OEM edition that came with your laptop and not a fully licensed copy, it would not be allowed for you to install this on a different machine - unless the VM is on the original machine (I guess - as it is running on the machine it was licensed for)... That being said, licensing drives me crazy and I do not know the finer details.

Comment: number of times of activation possible depends on how long you wait between these activations. activating one different pc every year works fine, even more often than 5 times (at least with XP Prof.)

Answer (score 2):

> I used the install disc that came with
>   my laptop (I have a paid license for
>   Windows XP).

if this is the OEM version that came with your computer, the activation is likely to fail as the key is registered and your VBox VM is technically a different computer.

but then, there is one easy way to find out. :)

if the activation via the internet fails, you can still try your luck with a MS representative over the phone and explain your situation, then you'll have the correct answer 'right from the horses mouth'.

Comment: This is exactly what happens to me with vmware.  I can boot the disk on the bare hardware, and it works.  When I boot it from vmware, I get a prompt for activation.  The key already in the system doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK retail copies of Windows XP can only be activated twice. Legally you should have a license for each VM however according to the Microsoft Licensing Agreement. The license agreement only allows one installed instance of the OS.

[This](http://www.technibble.com/windows-xp-home-license-agreement-translated/) entry does a detailed analysis of the Windows XP Home license however it is the same for Windows XP Professional.