# XP / Vista License on virtual box

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, license

My laptop came with vista and XP licenses. I since removed them and installed ubuntu instead. I have a piece of software that is known not to run on crossover or wine. When i try to install windows from my installation cd, it does not accept my licence, although legit.

what are the possible solutions to installing windows legally on virtual box using the licence codes that came with my computer?

**EDIT**
I'm installing windows on virtualbox 3.02

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://superuser.com/questions/27914/what-will-happen-if-i-active-my-windows-xp-vm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will almost certainly find that the license you have is an OEM license intended for use only on the hardware you bought the licenses with, so you will not be able to (legally) run them in a VM even on that hardware.

The best I would hope for, if you did not use either XP or Vista at all (i.e. you did not boot the OS all the way, stopping at the "agree to the EULA" screen or before) and can prove so, is that you might get a refund for the license you are not using (there have been stories of successful claims such as this on slashdot and similar sites recently.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you have to [call Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/) to get them to enable the license. Most home licenses are enabled for one computer at a time, and so one has to call in and get it switched. Some of the licenses are non-transferable, [like what happened to this guy](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=128390).